# Coloring various parts of an image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Looking to create a clothing customizer that would take an image of a piece of clothing and give the user the option of changing the colors.

Can this be done in HTML5 or Javascript? Any pointers would be appreciated if possible at all)

Answer (score 2):

**If there're numerous items on the page:**

You may create "template": image with only those parts are transparent, which will be customized and then alter background-color.

**If there're only few items.**

Inject image into canvas and then manipulate it. There's a library for that: [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I use a translucent image and a `background-color` property (CSS) to do this. You can change the background dynamically using Javascript.

Comment: I should have been clearer, but I'm ooking to change regions of the image with a new color, various regions with different colors per image